# What is wrong with this for loop and what it prints?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to write a program that compares the running time of two different lists, one being array based and one being a linked list. I have to run it twenty times at twenty different lengths, so I made a for loop to do this for me, it is supposed to run twenty times, but only printed out one thing, and then it made my computer very slow, and it said the process was still running on my IDE for a while. Heres the code, ask if you need more but this should be sufficient. I wanna know why the for loop only prints one thing and after that it says still running.

```
public class Foo4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      int diff = max / 20;
      int holder = 1;
      long test1time;
      long test2time;
      StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
      int t;

      for (t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
         AList test1 = new AList();
         Slist test2 = new Slist();

         for (int j = 0; j < holder; j++) {
            test1.addFirst("the");
            test2.addFirst("thee");
         }

         timer.reset();
         timer.start();
         test1.getLast();
         timer.stop();
         test1time = timer.getElapsedTime();
         timer.reset();
         timer.start();
         test2.getLast();
         timer.stop();
         test2time = timer.getElapsedTime();
         System.out.println(test1time + " : " + test2time);
         holder += diff;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: If you put in the time and effort to format your code well, others will more willingly put in the time and effort to help you. Yours is currently formatted terribly, making it hard to read since you've got code blocks that are not indented, other blocks that seem randomly indented, stacked curly braces...

Comment: Could I get something a little less vague? I would format it anyway that makes it easier, but I don't understand the problems with the formatting? How is someone new supposed to know how to format to make it easier for others?

Comment: Please learn the Java formatting standards, they are easy to find.

Comment: Fix your formatting doesn't tell me anything so don't say someone is trying to help me? It tells me you don't like my formatting. It doesn't say how to fix my problem, or even how to fix my formatting?

Comment: Please kindly help us by formatting your code if you want help . Actually this what above commentators wanted to said..

Comment: Your code has 3 `{` but 4 `}`. Copy & Paste error?

Comment: Also you have classes not shown, making it hard to figure out what could be wrong. And your holder variable is 1, so the for loop will only loop once of course.

Comment: In your code please check the value of holder, is it getting incremented? You set the value of holder as 1 so loop will run just once.

Comment: yes, that's a copy & paste error

Comment: Ok, the holder is off, this is because part of my program was deleted when I was trying to copy and paste it on here and this program was making the IDE not work, it was originally getting added to

Comment: `<ahem>` please indent that line you've added `</ahem>`. Also and again, what are your other classes not shown doing?

Comment: the program prints out 0 : 0, and then doesn't do the rest of the twenty loops? And it says program is running on my IDE and my IDE is hard to work with, like clicking on any part of it is delayed.

Comment: @trosy : You are adding `Integer.MAX_VALUE/20` elements to a list in the second iteration, no wonder why it is so slow.

Answer (score 3):

```
      int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      int diff = max / 20;
      int holder = 1;
...
      for (t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
          AList test1 = new AList();
          Slist test2 = new Slist();

          for (int j = 0; j < holder; j++) {
              test1.addFirst("the");
              test2.addFirst("thee");
          }
...
          holder+=diff
      }
```

You do realize that in your second iteration (when `t == 1` you are adding over a 100 million Strings to your lists? This could take some time, not to mention that your program might hang/fail due to memory limits.

Comment: The professor said that we had to go from one the the max size with evenly spaced intervals

Comment: For simplicity just suppose a maximum size for testing like set it to 50. If it works then you can increase it further. But for now just to test your logic/flow just keep that value down.

Comment: Ok, I did that, I set it to 10000, and the system is putting out all zeros for every part of the loop, there is no way it takes zero miliseconds for all of these to run?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i tried to run your code and i got the same output as said 0:0 every time. I dont know you are using which IDE. But I used eclipse and then I debugged your code. I set a breakpoint at line timer.reset() and then waited for some seconds and then moved to next line by pressing F6 and then moved to next step by having interval of 2 to 3 seconds for each F6 press. Then at the last it printed some value like: 2711 : 3559.

Now problem is that your code is executing so fast that it get start and end time same but when you debug it and check the value then it would show some result other than zero.

```
     timer.reset();//set a breakpoint over here. When debugger comes on this line press F6
     timer.start();//Wait for 3 seconds over here and then press F6. 
     test1.getLast();//Now at each below line wait for 3 seconds and then press F6
     timer.stop();
     test1time = timer.getElapsedTime();
     timer.reset();
     timer.start();
     test2.getLast();
     timer.stop();
     test2time = timer.getElapsedTime();
     System.out.println(test1time + " : " + test2time);
     holder += diff;
```